# excel find closest value in specific row in table

Tags: excel-formula

I am looking for a formula that gives me the closest value in a specific row in a table and another formula that gives me the column number where the value was found.

Thank you,
Debby

[image: Formula to find closest value in specific row in table]

Comment: closest number without exceeding or closest number even if its greater than?

Comment: I would need the closest lowest number.  e.g. for O6 - 7.500 - the result would also be 7.262,52

Answer (score 0):

Fill these two array formulas into b16:b17 finishing each with ctr+shift+enter.

```
=AGGREGATE(15, 6, (INDEX(B4:I11, MATCH(B14, A4:A11, 0), 0))/(ABS(INDEX(B4:I11, MATCH(B14, A4:A11, 0), 0)-B15)=MIN(ABS(INDEX(B4:I11, MATCH(B14, A4:A11, 0), 0)-B15))), 1)
=AGGREGATE(15, 6, COLUMN(A:H)/(ABS(INDEX(B4:I11, MATCH(B14, A4:A11, 0), 0)-B15)=MIN(ABS(INDEX(B4:I11, MATCH(B14, A4:A11, 0), 0)-B15))), 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Would it be possible to always give the closest "lowest amount"?  e.g. for O6 - 7.500 - the result would also be 7.262,52

Comment: Geez .. like for real... get like serioua or something ... whatever .;..